# Spring Boot2.1.7 Dependencies not copied into jar file

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-plugin

I Am migrating an existing spring application to spring boot.I am not  able to run it as a spring boot application.When i run jar file via command prompt its showing "no main manifest attribute".Now am adding following plugins in my pom.xml file.previous error resolved.

pom.xml

```
  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                                <mainClass>com.services.api.ServiceMain</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy</id>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>
                                    ${project.build.directory}/lib
                                </outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

now its showing another error

[image]

manifest.mf

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: Service
Implementation-Version: 7.0.0.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: Administrator
Implementation-Vendor-Id: MainProject
Class-Path: lib/abc-1.0.jar lib/abc1-1.0.jar

Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_202
Implementation-URL: http://maven.apache.org
Main-Class: com.services.api.ServiceMain
```

lib folder is not present in my target or inside jar files and my jar file size is 64 kb only.

build my application using following commad

```
clean install
```

How can i fix this issue. Already go through some stack overflow link,not fix my issue

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <start-class>org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher</start-class>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: can you put complete pom.xml

Comment: I just  created a project using pom given by you, there seems nothing wrong with your pom, try creating new clean project

Comment: Are you able to run jar file using java -jar service.jar

Comment: Yes without any issue

Comment: If you can provide your project on GitHub , i can give a try

Comment: its not possible.

Comment: @arj assuming you have seen the repository, I will be deleting same  soon

Comment: I have checked. Thanks for your effort Shailesh